# (Nested Addevent listener)why does a AddEventListener click event act differently via an Arrow and normal function

Tags: javascript

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  // Scenario 1 
  const btn = document.querySelector(".test");
  btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
    var x = document.createElement('p');
    x.className = "di";
    x.style.background = "aqua";
    for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
      x.textContent = ' Change background color for ' + `${i}` + " element";
      x.id = 'para' + `${i}`;
      fragment.append(x.cloneNode(true));
    }
    document.body.append(fragment);
    //Nested addeventlistener
    document.getElementById("para1").addEventListener("click", () => {
      para1.style.background = "yellow"
    });
    document.getElementById("para2").addEventListener("click", () => {
      para2.style.background = "yellow"
    });

    function changeBackgroundColor(elem) {
      elem.style.background = "yellow";
    }
        //Nested addeventlistener

    document.getElementById("para3").addEventListener("click", changeBackgroundColor(para3));
    document.getElementById("para4").addEventListener("click", changeBackgroundColor(para4));
  });
});
```

```html
<button class="test">create 4 elements</button>
```

Step 1: Click on the HTML Button 'create 4 elements' to create 4 `<p>` elements.

Observation 1: for the **1st and 2nd `<p>` elements** which **have** arrow function inside their addeventlisteners , the individual `<p>` elements need to be explicitly clicked individually to change their background color from aqua to yellow.

Observation 2:  for the **3rd and 4th `<p>`velements** which **dont** have arrow function inside their addeventlistener ,the background color has defaulted to yellow **without** clicking on the 3rd or 4th `<p>` elements

So does this mean the click event in Observation 2 has no effect ? Also note there are nested `AddEventListeners`

Comment: What is `actionEventListener`? They're just called event listeners, and `addEventListener()` adds them.

Comment: You're not passing a function reference, you're calling the function immediately.

Comment: addEventListener expects a function as 2nd parameter.   `changeBackgroundColor` is a function, but `changeBackgroundColor(param2)` is equal to the value returned by executing that piece of code (undefined).

Comment: @james so how to pass a param then?

Comment: Wrap it in an anon function, `element.addEventListener("click", () => changeBackgroundColor(para3))`